# Android: How to show gridview initially without any images and whenever user clicks on the empty grid-view cell then the image have to be displayed?

Tags: java, android, gridview

is it possible to show empty grid-view(it is not showing like a filled one it is showing like a single bold bar line).

so i tried to fill it with black draw-able images then it is showing like a filled one.

My app contains two grid-views one is with images and one should look like empty one.

A user can pick a image from grid-view 1 and place it on the grid-view 2,

now i want to get the tag of the image which was placed in grid-view 2. But i'm getting Null
Am i Right Or Wrong please Reply

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GridView g=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    g.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
    GridView g2=(GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView2);
    g2.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter2(getApplicationContext()));

    g.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
            int position, long id) 
        {  

             System.out.println("pressent G1 child Tag is,,,,"+(Integer)g.getChildAt(tt).getTag());

        }  
     });

   g2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
    {
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
             int position, long id) 
         {  ImageAdapter ia=new ImageAdapter(getApplicationContext());

             /* ImageView imv;      

             if(v!=null)
            {
                imv=(ImageView)v;
            }
            else
            {
                imv=new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
                imv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(40,40));
                imv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                imv.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
                imv.setBackgroundColor(5555);

            } */
            imv.setImageResource(ia.imageid[tt]);
            System.out.println("tag of placed image is"+(Integer)g2.getChildAt(position).getTag());
 // IN THIS GRIDVIEW2 PLEASE HELP ME HOW I CAN GET THE PLACED IMAGE TAG(the images which are in gridview1 and image placed in gridview2 are same but iam not able to get the tag it return null)

             }        
         }
    });
```

ImageAdapter.java

```
if(arg1!=null)
    {
        imv=(ImageView)arg1;
    }
    else
    {
        imv=new ImageView(cont);
        imv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(40,40));
        imv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imv.setPadding(0,0,0,0);

    }
    imv.setTag(arg0);
    imv.setImageResource(imageid[arg0]);
    return imv;
```

ImageAdapter2.java

```
if(arg1!=null)
    {
        imv=(ImageView)arg1;
    }
    else
    {
        imv=new ImageView(cont);
        imv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(40,40));
        imv.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imv.setPadding(0,0,0,0);

    }
    imv.setImageResource(imageid[0]);  //---> this is to set Black images in gridview so that it will      look like a box
    return imv;
```

Comment: i removed @override from mainactivity.java file, is this is the reason to my problem?